# Monitor not recognized in Ubuntu 13.04 - gateway NV59c

Tags: 13.04, monitor

Recently upgraded to 13.04 and ubuntu isn't recognizing laptop monitor. I could connect using external monitor and tried the "mirror" options. It shows the monitor, but could not make the laptop as the primary to keep the laptop as standalone. I had the similar problem in one of the earlier versions, can't recall how I solved. Now I'm struck. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your monitor is not reconized, you have only one option:

Step 1) To use your monitor you can configure x.org with custom settings for you monitor so you can use your monitor on your current ubuntu version.

step 2) submit a improvement on bugs.ubuntu.com or bugzilla.kernel.org/ to add your monitor driver. This way your might have your monitor settings available in the next release.